# Как включить свой класс в проект на GWT?

Tags: gwt, java, eclipse, java-ee

Как подключить свой класс к gwt проекту? В классе собираются данные из базы данных. Т.е. по  запросу с клиента на стороне сервера должен выполнять метод из моего класса. Однако при обращении к серверу всегда возникает ошибка `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`. В Build Path все библиотеки подключены, но я так понял, что нужно прописать пути еще куда-то. 
Используется eclipse gwt plugin.

Comment: А ваш класс он где? На стороне сервера или клиента?

Comment: На стороне сервера. Я уже нашел как именно подключить класс. Но возникают проблемы с внешними библиотеками. Я добавил их в \war\WEB-INF\lib, но во время обращения к серверу возникает ошибка "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.orientechnologies.orient.core.Orient"

Comment: Посмотри на `CLASSPATH` на стороне сервера. Если класс правильно лежит в `CLASSPATH` то проблем не должно возникнуть.

Comment: Странно, сменил базу данных с orientdb на mysql - все работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отключить бесполезный Google App Engine (Project -> Properties -> Google -> AppEngine -> Use Google App Engine -> снять галочку). Загрузить все библиотеки в папку `MyProject\war\WEB-INF\lib`. Добавить все библиотеки в Java Build Path. That's it. Однако, многие классы не работают на стороне клиента, зато на стороне сервера все пашет.